# React - Rendering a component by triggering an event in another component

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

The parent component connects to a Google Cloud FireStore and saves all data in to cards using setCards hooks.

Next we import two children components in to our parent component:

```
<UpdateCard card={card} />
<AddCard totalDoclNumbers={totalDoclNumbers} />
```

**PARENT Component - DockList**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import UpdateCard from './UpdateCard';
import AddCard from './AddCard';

const DocList = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [beginAfter, setBeginAfter] = useState(0);
  const [totalDoclNumbers, setTotalDoclNumbers] = useState(0);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await db
        .collection('FlashCards')
        .orderBy('customId')
        .startAfter(beginAfter)
        .get();
      setCards(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [beginAfter]);

 
  return (
      <ul className='list'>
        {cards.map((card) => (
          <li key={card.id} className='list__item' data-id={card.id}>
            <UpdateCard card={card} />
          </li>
        ))}
        <AddCard totalDoclNumbers={totalDoclNumbers} />
      </ul>
  );
};

export default DocList;
```

Inside UpdateCard, we list all data stored in cards using an unordered list:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const UpdateCard = ({ card }) => {
  const [translatedText, setTranslatedText] = useState(card.translatedText);
  const [customId, setCustomId] = useState(card.customId);

  const onUpdate = async () => {
    await db
      .collection('FlashCards')
      .doc(card.id)
      .update({ ...card, customId, originalText, translatedText, imgURL });    
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type='text'
        value={customId}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCustomId(Number(e.target.value));
        }}
      />
      <textarea
        value={translatedText}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setTranslatedText(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={onUpdate}>
        Update
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default UpdateCard;
```

Finally in the second child component, called **AddCard**, we have a button, which triggers the function onAdd to add new data in to our FireStore collection.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const AddCard = ({ totalDoclNumbers }) => {
  const [newTranslatedText, setNewTranslatedText] = useState([]);
  const nextNumber = totalDoclNumbers + 1;

  const onAdd = async () => {
    await db.collection('FlashCards').add({
      translatedText: newTranslatedText,
      customId: Number(nextNumber),
    });   
  };

  return (
    <ul className='list'>
      <li key={nextNumber}>
        <input
          type='text'
          className='list__input'
          defaultValue={nextNumber}
        />
        <textarea
          onChange={(e) => setNewTranslatedText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={onAdd}>
          Add
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};

export default AddCard;
```

It all works. When you click the button inside the second child component **AddCard** component, the new data get stored in to the collection.

But to be able to see new added data, I need to render **UpdateCard** and that's exactly, what I'm struggling with.

**How can I achieve that click on the button inside the AddCard component, triggers rendering in UpdateCard component.**

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so first on `DocList` add a callback function:

```
const DocList = () => {
  ...
  const [addButtonClickCount, setAddButtonClickCount] = useState(0);
  ...
  return (
      <ul className='list'>
        {cards.map((card) => (
          <li key={card.id} className='list__item' data-id={card.id}>
            <UpdateCard card={card} addButtonClickCount={addButtonClickCount}/>
          </li>
        ))}
        <AddCard totalDoclNumbers={totalDoclNumbers} onAddButtonClick={(card) => {
           setAddButtonClickCount(c => c + 1)
           setCards(cards => [...cards, {...card.data(), id: card.idcard}])
        }} />
      </ul>
  );
};
```

then call `onAddButtonClick` which is passed to `AddCard` as props when needed:

```
const AddCard = ({ totalDoclNumbers, onAddButtonClick }) => {
...
const onAdd = async () => {
    // Somehow you gotta get value of newly created card:
    let card = await db.collection('FlashCards').add({
      translatedText: newTranslatedText,
      customId: Number(nextNumber),
    }); 
    
    // pass the newly created card here so you could use it in `UpdateCard`
    onAddButtonClick(card) // this looks likes where it belongs.
  };
```

this will result in rerendering of `UpdateCard` component since it's getting `addButtonClickCount` as props, if you want to do something in `UpdateCard` after add button is clicked, you could use `useEffect` with `[addButtonClickCount]` dependency array.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me.I even passed addButtonClickCount props to UpdateCard like this: const UpdateCard = ({ card, addButtonClickCount }) => {
....
  const [renderUi, setRenderUi] = useState(false);
....

  useEffect(() => {
    setRenderUi(true);
  }, [addButtonClickCount]);

Comment: put some `console.log` in `UpdateCard` to see if it's rerendering. and tell me the results

Comment: I now have this code inside UpdateCard: useEffect(() => {
    setRenderUi(true);
    console.log('UpdateCard is rendering');
  }, [addButtonClickCount]);
And when I click on Add button inside AddCard, I can see the log from UpdateCard in console. But the new data doesn't get added to the UI.

Comment: I've edited my answer, keep in mind that I don't know if `db.collection().add` returns the created instance, you gotta figure that on your own, this answer is just for giving you the idea of how two sibling components can pass data.

Comment: Thanks StackedQ. I really appreciate your help. Now when I click on Add button, the UI gets updated and a new row get added to the table which shows all the dat from collection. But the new row is empty and doesn't contain any data. I checked the FireStore collection and the new data is in the collection but not showing in the newly rendered row.

Comment: Based on what you've already done for creating cards array, I edited my answer on `onAddButtonClick` in `DocList`, check it out.

Comment: @user1941537 still any issues?